# Electronic shutter in timelapse video in Nikon D3300

Tags: nikon, timelapse, shutter

I have searched there is no time lapse video option in Nikon D3300 and I found that we can take time lapse photo using intervalometer.

However, with the intervalometer the photos are taken using mechanical shutter.

1. Is there any way that we can set intervalometer to use electronic shutter?
2. If I take time lapse video using mechanical shutter does it reduce the life of camera shutter?
   (I mean if the camera is taking 1000 or more photos in one day I guess shutter will break one day)

Note: I know we can take video and convert into time lapse video but I want to take time lapse using electronic shutter :)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid Nikon D3300 do not have electronic shutter. You can check documentations and specifications [here](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3300/spec.htm)

And as you can see the life of shutter of D3300 is 100k (average). But do not expect when you reach the limit shutter will stop working at all.

Also you want to make timelapse so you should pay the "price" :)

Difference between electronic and mechanical shutter:

[link1](http://www.juzaphoto.com/article.php?l=en&t=mechanical_and_electronic_shutter)

Comment: 1.Is there any way to record video while the camera screen is off?
2.Is there any opensource code to manage nikon camera remotely and override the video frame rate to 1 fps?

Comment: Please ask new questions. Practice in SE is to ask one question and expect answers to it

Comment: @RomeoNinov In the link that you provided under shutter it says "Electronically controlled vertical-travel focal-plane shutter" So how can you tell that it doesn't have electronic shutter ?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Can you join for a chat ? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31959/chat-between-photeur-and-romeo

Comment: @Phototeur, to have mechanical unit which is electronically controlled and to have electronic shutter are two very different things. Please check my updated answer